# Use of Stripe api keys across multiple domains

Tags: stripe-payments

Does Stripe allow for the use of their api keys across more than one domain or can you only use the 'live' keys on the domain that you specify in your Stripe account?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you specify a domain in Stripe's settings? No, you're not limited to one domain…

Comment: @deceze I thought you had to indicate your website in the setup process / settings

Answer (score 1):

You're only limited by domain if you use client-side only Checkout: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout

For every other product you can use your keys for any domain, even multiples.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that if you use STRIPE and credit-card payments on multiple domains, you can only define ONE(!) Statement Descriptor. And you can not change it (not as a parameter)

If you have domain_xxx and domain_PPP and customers will shop on PPP, they will maybe see on their credit-card statement that the bought from XXX, they get confused and start a fraud-conflict after 3-4 months...

Comment: good advice!  thanks!